# An identity involving Chain Function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

A function $f \colon \mathbb Z^2 \to \mathbb R$ is called a  *chain function* if all of the following conditions hold:

1. $\forall x \in \mathbb Z \quad f(x,x)=0$.
2. $f(1,0)=1$.
3. $\forall x, \, y \in \mathbb Z \quad f(x+1,y)f(x,y+1)-f(x+1,y+1)f(x,y)=(-1)^{x+y}$.
4. $f(x,y)=0 \implies f(x+1,y-1)+f(x-1,y+1)=f(x+1,y+1)+f(x-1,y-1)$.

Prove that every chain function also satisfies the following relation $\forall x, \, y,\, t \in \mathbb Z$: $$f(x,y)=f(x,t)f(t+1,y)+f(x,t+1)f(t,y).$$
My teacher found this to be true and I guess it is so. But no formal proof. Any help?

Comment: yeah. darn. sorry.

Comment: Hint: prove for $t=1$ and then use induction?

Comment: Hi I tried proving for $t=1$ but haven't been able to do so. Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: Hint 2: (3) practically describes the determinant of the 2x2 matrix found in $(x,y)$.

Comment: What do you mean by $(x,y)$ ? and how do you conclude so? and please prove for $t=1$ thus paving the path for induction. Thanks.

Comment: Dear @PeterHorvath please could you give your proof? After a long time of fiddling with it, I have lost all hope. I tried to consider the matrix where the $(i,j)$-th entry is $f(i,j)$ then I had the matrix has all diagonal elements zero, and initial entry 1. But I couldn't use your idea to use 3 and 4. I can't proceed anymore. Thanks.